# cuda double precision logarithm error

Tags: math, cuda, logarithm, double-precision

I'm using C for CUDA on 3.0 computing capability and have to use
built-in logarithm function of double precision. I found that for 
that purpose I should use `double log(double x)` function ([documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE_g28ce8e15ef5149c271eba95663becba2.html)).
But, if I pass a really small number within double precision scope
(e.g. `double x = 6.73E-42`),
`log(x)` function returns `-Infinity`. In Java `Math.log()` function for the same
value returns `-94.802`. Is this a bug within CUDA math library or am I getting something wrong?

EDIT:
Here's the code I'm using in the kernel function

```
#include "math.h"
extern "C"
__global__ void smallLog(double* in, int n)
{
   int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   if (i<n){
      double x = in[i];
      in[i] = log(x);
   }
}
```

Comment: CUDA is probably calculating with `float`s. Then 6.73E-42 is 0.

Comment: You can check whether the hardware supports double by checking the SM version: major/minor members of cudaDeviceProp, or cuDeviceComputeCapability(). double precision is supported only on SM 1.3 and later hardware

Comment: I have a GeForce GTX 680 with compute capability 3.0. It should support double precision computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are compiling for compute capability 3.0 (`nvcc -arch sm_30`).

By default, nvcc compiles for compute capability 1.0, which is single precision only and (as others have pointed out already) 6.73E-42 is zero in single precision and log(0) = -Infinity.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, the answer should be -94.802.

Try splitting `log(6.73E-42)` into

`log(6.731E-20) + log(1E-22) = [(-44.145)+(-50.66)]=(-94.802)`

Or, if you want you can split into more pieces and finally add. Am sorry, my device doesn't support double-precision. That's the answer i can give.